# Read an image pixel by pixel (ndimage/ndarray)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, multidimensional-array, ndimage

I have an image that is stored as an `ndarray`. I would like to iterate over each pixel in this array.

I can iterate over each element of the array like this:

```
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np

l = ndimage.imread('sample.gif', mode="RGB")

for x in np.nditer(l):
    print x
```

This gives ie:

```
...
153
253
153
222
253
111
...
```

These are the values of each color in the pixels, one after the other. What I would like instead is to  read these values 3 by 3 to produce something like this:

```
...
(153, 253, 153)
(222, 253, 111)
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest is to reshape the numpy array first, and then go about printing.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Also, this should help you.
[Reshaping a numpy array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627647/reshaping-a-numpy-array-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

You can try zipping the list with itself:

```
from itertools import izip
for x in izip(l[0::3],l[1::3],l[2::3]):
    print x
```

Output:

```
(153, 253, 153)
(222, 253, 111)
```

**UPDATE:** Welp, I was bad at numpy in 2015. Here is my updated answer:

`scipy.ndimage.imread` is now deprecated and it is recommended to use `imageio.imread`. However for the purpose of this question I tested both and they behave the same.

Since we are reading the image in as `RGB`, we will get an array of `heightxwidthx3`, which is already what you want. You are losing the shape when you iterate over the array with `np.nditer`.

```
>>> img = imageio.imread('sample.jpg')
>>> img.shape
(456, 400, 3)
>>> for r in img:
...     for s in r:
...         print(s)
... 
[63 46 52]
[63 44 50]
[64 43 50]
[63 42 47]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

While the answer @Imran works, it is not an intuitive solution... this could make it difficult to debug. Personally, I'd avoid any manipulation of the image, and then process with for loops.

Alternative 1:

```
img = ndimage.imread('sample.gif')
rows, cols, depth = np.shape(img)

r_arr, c_arr = np.mgrid[0:rows, 0:cols]

for r, c in zip(r_arr.flatten(), c_arr.flatten()):
    print(img[r,c])
```

Or you could do this directly with nested for loops:

```
for row in img:
    for pixel in row:
        print(pixel)
```

Note that these are flexible; they work for any 2D image regardless of depth.