# converting appended images list in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

I have a list which I created after appending the images from a folder

```
samples=[]    
for filename in glob.glob(path + '/*.png'):
    samples.append(misc.imread(filename))
```

And a sample of the list looks like

```
[array([[ 4,  4,  4, ...,  5,  5,  4],
   [ 5,  5,  5, ...,  6,  6,  5],
   [ 5,  5,  5, ...,  6,  6,  4],
   ..., 
   [12, 12, 11, ..., 12, 12,  7],
   [12, 11, 11, ..., 13, 12,  7],
   [11, 11, 10, ..., 12, 12,  7]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 4,  4,  4, ...,  7,  7,  6],
   [ 5,  5,  5, ...,  6,  6,  4],
   [ 5,  5,  5, ...,  7,  7,  5]], dtype=uint8)]
```

How it convert the image's dimensions in a Pandas DataFrame. when I tried to do it with

```
df=pd.DataFrame(samples)
```

It gives me an error

```
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input
```

Please Suggest- I will appreciate every help

Comment: You have a list of 2-d arrays which makes `samples` a 3-d object. Look into Pandas' panels which are designed to hold 3-d data.

Comment: i want to convert into a 2d dataframe only, so that I can use isomaps techniques going ahead

Comment: Then you need to put each element of the list into its own dataframe or create a dataframe with the inner lists as elements in your cells.

Comment: Do you want to "flatten" each image?  That is, do you want to reshape it from a two-dimensional array with shape `(m, n)` to a 1-d array with length `m*n`?  If so, do you want the data for each image to be a row or a column in the DataFrame?

Comment: A more fundamental question:  why do you want to use a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: Will this do: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(samples))`?

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it into a pandas [panel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html)

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('path/Picture_1.png')
imgPanel = pd.Panel(img)
```

For more info see: [Panel- Introduction](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/dsintro.html#panel), [n-dimensional Panel (Experimental)](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#n-dimensional-panels-experimental), [Cookbook- Panel](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/cookbook.html#panels), [Panel-nd cookbook](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/cookbook.html#panelnd)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .reshape(-1) while appending an image.

```
for filename in glob.glob(path + '/*.png'):
    samples.append(misc.imread(filename).reshape(-1))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(samples)
```

If you want to 3d version please read
[Reshaping a numpy array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627647/reshaping-a-numpy-array-in-python)