# array transform in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working with python, and I Got an array which looks like (750 ,), and it is a matrix with 750 rows and 1 column. but I would like to make it look like (750, 1). to be specific, I would like to do a transform :
 (750, )--->(750,1). any advice ?

Comment: Seen `np.reshape`?... or just `arr = arr[:, None]`

Comment: `arr = np.expand_dims(arr, -1)`

Comment: Please post a sample of your actual data and what you have already tried to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's create a (750,) array :

```
import numpy as np
test_array = np.array(range(750))

test_array.shape 
# Returns (750,)
```

You can create a new array with the shape you want with the [`np.ndarray.reshape()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape) method :

```
new_array = test_array.reshape([750,1])
```

It is equivalent to

```
new_array = np.reshape(test_array,[750,1])
```

Comment: Thank you bobolafrite !  it is exactly what  I am look for , and I was stuck in this for one hour. thanks.

Comment: Also  `new_array = test_array[:, np.newaxis]` (or, equivalently, `new_array = test_array[:, None]` as you were already told by Coldspeed) — do yourself a favor and google for "numpy broadcasting" to discover one of the strengths of Numpy...

Comment: Yes, this one is interesting too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627647/reshaping-a-numpy-array-in-python
@harold Mark the answer as accepted if you're satisfied with it :)